# Error launching simple Eureka-Service server

Tags: java, spring, cloud, netflix-eureka

I am following Josh Long's presentation at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5q8B6lYhFvE&feature=youtu.be .  I am following his examples. At about 34 minutes in he demos setting up the Eureka service.

This service uses the config-service. My config service is running and exposes the information the eureka service needs. I have checked my `bootstrap.properties` and they look correct according to his presentation. However the eureka service does not complete and does not seem to be accessing the config service. My other service does reach the config service and works fine.

The eureka service should come up at http://localhost:8761/ but does not. It is at 8080.

eureka service bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.application.name= eureka-service
spring.cloud.config.uri= http://localhost:8888
```

**First error:**

```
2016-10-13 18:43:00.088 ERROR 7464 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

**Second error**

```
2016-10-13 18:43:00.097 ERROR 7464 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_EUREKA-SERVICE/RB-64-PC.Home:eureka-service - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. I had accidently added the "config server" dependency into  the project when I created it. I am using the site "http://start.spring.io/" as per the video. Adding the config server dependencies kept the initialization from accessing the actual config server running on another port.